# Copy LINQ query results into existing DataTable with faster performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq, datatable

I am looking for a way to improve the performance of C# code and would appreciate any help.

There are 2 tables: Table_1 and Table_2, and I want to collect data from Table_2 and save in Table_1 in the following form:

Table_1

| Date | Some_Stat |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01 | 23.7 |
| 2021-06-02 | 12.6 |
| 2021-06-03 | 47.9 |

Table_2

| Date | ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-02 | 4 | 21 | 23 | 13 |
| 2021-06-02 | 3 | 67 | 31 | 25 |
| 2021-06-01 | 3 | 45 | 54 | 33 |
| 2021-06-03 | 3 | 71 | 28 | 51 |
| 2021-06-03 | 4 | 26 | 83 | 24 |

My goal: Table_1 after join

| Date | Some_Stat | A_3 | B_3 | C_3 | A_4 | B_4 | C_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01 | 23.7 | 45 | 54 | 33 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-06-02 | 12.6 | 67 | 31 | 25 | 21 | 23 | 13 |
| 2021-06-03 | 47.9 | 71 | 28 | 51 | 26 | 83 | 24 |

In order to achieve this I used the code below, which works, but is very slow, especially when there are thousands of IDs. Basically what the code does is making first the required join and transferring LINQ join results to existing Table_1 (copies the columns).
I have checked the performance time and the LINQ query is always very fast (time: 0ms), but the data transfer is the problem.

```
List<int> ids = Table_2.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<int>("ID").Distinct().ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
    {
       Table_1.Columns.Add($"A_{ids[i]}", typeof(double));
       Table_1.Columns.Add($"B_{ids[i]}", typeof(double));
       Table_1.Columns.Add($"C_{ids[i]}", typeof(double));
    }

for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
{
   // LINQ join (fast)
   var joinedTables = from T1 in Table_1.AsEnumerable()
            join T2 in Table_2.Select($"ID = {ids[i]}").AsEnumerable()
            on (String)T1["Date"] equals (String)T2["Date"]
            into T1_and_T2
            from TT in T1_and_T2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
              {
                 Date = (String)T1["Date"],
                 A = TT != null ? (double)TT["A"] : 0.0,
                 B = TT != null ? (double)TT["B"] : 0.0,
                 C = TT != null ? (double)TT["C"] : 0.0,
              };
   // data transfer (very slow)
   for (int day = 0; day < joinedTables.Count(); day++)
   {
     Table_1.Rows[day][$"A_{ids[i]}"] = joinedTables.ElementAt(day).A;
     Table_1.Rows[day][$"B_{ids[i]}"] = joinedTables.ElementAt(day).B;
     Table_1.Rows[day][$"C_{ids[i]}"] = joinedTables.ElementAt(day).C;
   }
}
```

Also instead of the data transfer version above I have tried another way, but it is as slow as the previous:

```
int day = 0;
foreach( var row in joinedTables)
{
  Table_1.Rows[day][$"A_{ids[i]}"] = row.A;
  Table_1.Rows[day][$"B_{ids[i]}"] = row.B;
  Table_1.Rows[day][$"C_{ids[i]}"] = row.C;
}
```

I am also open to new approaches on how to collect data from `Table_2` in `Table_1`. There could be a way to use build-in functions (written in C or C++) which will access Machine Code directly ( for example, a function which copies columns from one table to another table, like in python) in order to avoid looping through rows.

Note: In the original problem `Table_1` may have up to 500 rows and 10 columns and `Table_2` may have up to 5000 rows per day and populated 50 - 100%. The solutions above in the extreme case will take from 2 to 4 hours, which is very slow ( I believe this could be done within minutes).

Comment: Your problem is a fundamental misunderstanding of LINQ. The assignment to `joinTables` does not execute the join, it creates a data structure that represents the join calculation. When you call `ElementAt`, it runs the join, then skips through the result to find the element. Change `joinTables` to `joinList`, put the LINQ in `()` and put `.ToList()` on the end. Replace `ElementAt(day)` with `[day]`.

Comment: Note also that `T1_and_T2` is not that; it is just the joined `T2` (I would name it `T2j`). It doesn't have any of `T1` in it. Then your next `from` would be `from T2 in T2j.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, however it is as slow as it was with ElementAt()

Comment: It should be a lot faster than `ElementAt`, but I decided a whole different approach was better, so I posted that as my answer.

Comment: I would suggest to include in the question some specific metrics about the sizes of the associated tables (`Table_1` and `Table_2`), including the actual number of columns of the `Table_1`. Without this info, it's very difficult for anyone who is reading this question to guess where the problem might be. Ideally you should include a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the problematic behavior (including specific time measurements). Doing so will improve significantly the question, and will make it eligible for upvotes.

Comment: You are right @TheodorZoulias, I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use a different approach. A `DataTable` is not a particularly fast object, and looking up columns to set values is slow. Creating a new `DataTable` to replace `Table_1` can be much faster since you can use the `DataRowCollection.Add()` method to quickly add rows.

Using a `Dictionary` to convert `Table_2` allows for much faster lookup than `ElementAt` as well.

```
var joinDict = (from T2 in Table_2.AsEnumerable()
                select new {
                    Date = T2.Field<string>("Date"),
                    ID = T2.Field<int>("ID"),
                    A = T2.Field<double>("A"),
                    B = T2.Field<double>("B"),
                    C = T2.Field<double>("C"),
                })
                .ToDictionary(t2 => (t2.Date, t2.ID));

List<int> ids = Table_2.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<int>("ID")).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

var ans = Table_1.Clone();
for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++) {
    ans.Columns.Add($"A_{ids[i]}", typeof(double));
    ans.Columns.Add($"B_{ids[i]}", typeof(double));
    ans.Columns.Add($"C_{ids[i]}", typeof(double));
}

foreach (DataRow row in Table_1.Rows) {
    var newRow = new List<object> { row.Field<string>("Date") };
    foreach (var id in ids) {
        if (joinDict.TryGetValue((row.Field<string>("Date"), id), out var t2))
            newRow.AddRange(new object[] { t2.A, t2.B, t2.C });
        else
            newRow.AddRange(new object[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 });
    }
    ans.Rows.Add(newRow.ToArray());
}
Table_1 = ans;
```

In testing with 100 days in `Table_1` and 500 rows per day in `Table_2` 75% populated, I get about 128x speedup.

Comment: wow, it's so cool, it seems to work as you say, thanks @NetMage . I just need to understand now how to do for loop over this table now and make other minor changes...

Comment: I was not sure if I should open a new topic, I have a short question: what is the proper way to loop over the Table_1 ? ( I am just struggling with it and can't find any way, any link or hint will be appreciated)

Comment: @klop52 Depends on why you are looping? What are you trying to accomplish? The easiest is `foreach (DataRow dr in Table_1.Rows)` or `foreach (var dr in Table_1.AsEnumerable())` like the add loop in the answer.

Comment: Sometimes I also need to compare the values between the rows, so for loop would be appropriate, but when I try it with: Table_1.Rows[i]["A"] == 40 , then it doesn't work. Is there any way also to apply for loop? So I want to access certain rows and certain columns at the same time and save the sum in a variable. I tried also: double S = 0; S = double.Parse(Table_1.Rows[i]["A"].ToString()) + double.Parse(Table_1.Rows[i]["B"].ToString()); , but this brought me an input error

Comment: @klop52 There should be no "A" column - they are all "A_#" based on "ID". Also, always use `Field<T>("column name")` instead of `[]` to ensure your `==` is using proper types.

Comment: Ah, true, sorry. Thanks for help! I will try

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup) LINQ operator, and create an efficient `Lookup<DateTime, DataRow>` structure from the contents of the `Table_2`. This readonly structure will contain one `IGrouping<DateTime, DataRow>` for each unique date, and each grouping will contain all the `DataRow`s that are associated with this date:

```
var lookup = Table_2.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date"));
```

Then for every row of the `Table_1` you will be able to find quickly all the associated rows of the `Table_2`:

```
foreach (DataRow row1 in Table_1.Rows)
{
    DateTime date = row1.Field<DateTime>("Date");
    IEnumerable<DataRow> group = lookup[date];
    if (group == null) continue;
    foreach (DataRow row2 in group)
    {
        int id = row2.Field<int>("ID");
        row1[$"A_{id}"] = row2.Field<double>("A");
        row1[$"B_{id}"] = row2.Field<double>("B");
        row1[$"C_{id}"] = row2.Field<double>("C");
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** It seems that your performance problem is not associated with joining the two `DataTable`s, but with updating an extremely wide `DataTable`, that contains hundreds or even thousands of `DataColumn`s. Apparently `DataTable`s are not optimized for scenarios like this. The complexity of updating any column of a `DataRow` is O(n²), where N is the total number of columns. To overcome this problem you can export all the values stored in a `DataRow` through the [`ItemArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.itemarray) property, manipulate these values, and finally import them back through the same property. The performance can be improved even further by using the [`BeginLoadData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.beginloaddata) and [`EndLoadData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.endloaddata) methods.

```
Table_1.BeginLoadData();
foreach (DataRow row1 in Table_1.Rows)
{
    DateTime date = row1.Field<DateTime>("Date");
    IEnumerable<DataRow> group = lookup[date];
    if (group == null) continue;
    object[] values = row1.ItemArray; // Export the raw data
    foreach (DataRow row2 in group)
    {
        int id = row2.Field<int>("ID");
        values[Table_1.Columns[$"A_{id}"].Ordinal] = row2.Field<double>("A");
        values[Table_1.Columns[$"B_{id}"].Ordinal] = row2.Field<double>("B");
        values[Table_1.Columns[$"C_{id}"].Ordinal] = row2.Field<double>("C");
    }
    row1.ItemArray = values; // Import the updated data
}
Table_1.EndLoadData();
```

Comment: Nice, thanks!! I have tried it and it also works, however is just 10% faster, I thought there could be a way to use some build in functions (for instance, copying columns from one table to another) which are written in C or C++, in order to access Machine Code directly (like in python)

Comment: @klop52 hmm, I would expect it to be pretty fast. Could you measure the time using a [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch), start it just before the `ToLookup` and stop it just after the outer `foreach` loop, and report the `ElapsedMilliseconds`? My suspicion is that there is something else that it's slow, before or after, and affects the overall speed.

Comment: Execution Time for data preparation with old version: 0h 0m 10s 358ms  ; Execution Time for data preparation with updated version: 0h 0m 9s 83ms.

Comment: @klop52 how many rows (approximately) are in the tables `Table_1` and `Table_2`?

Comment: I am trying it now for 23 days and around 430 IDs

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will be able to test it in a couple of days